# Checking if ip is correct

Tags: bash, shell-script, ip

I have a script that requires the IP to be written correctly.

Examples:

```
192.168.0.1 -> echo ok
1.2.3.4 -> echo ok
4.3.a.3 -> echo Not ok
300.52.256.1 -> not ok
1.2.3.4.5 -> not ok
```

I've tried this:

```
 if [[ $ip =~ ^[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}$ ]]
               then
                            echo SUCCES!
```

But this is not good enough since `300.2.3.4` is a good IP for this expression.

The only accepted IPs should be something like `(0-255).(0-255).(0-255).0-255)`

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/25969006/2072269

Comment: Thank you,i found what I was looking for

Answer (score 1):

OK,I found out the answer:

```
if [[ "$ip" =~ ^((25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\.){3}(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)$ ]];
           then
                                echo SUCCES!
```

Thanks to @muru for helping!